# Is there any difference between one or many "var" statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)
>   [What is the advantage of initializing multiple javascript variables with the same var keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455445/what-is-the-advantage-of-initializing-multiple-javascript-variables-with-the-sam)

I have the following code:

```
var row = $link.attr('data-row'),
    a = 2,
    b = a;
```

Is this exactly the same as:

```
var row = $link.attr('data-row');
var a = 2;
var b = a;
```

When I use jslint it keeps suggesting I use just the one var. What do people normally do to make the code most readable. Also is there a way to stop jslint complaining?

Comment: No, that's the same. The first version is just a shortcut.

Comment: The code is shorter with one var. Can't think of any other differences.

Comment: Speed. The first is faster than the 2nd

Comment: @SReject got any citation or evidence for that?

Comment: @SReject do you have source ? Speed of what ? download and parsing or execution ?

Comment: @SReject - There won't be any difference in speed: http://jsperf.com/single-var-statement-vs-multiple-statements

Comment: faster to read at least (but nothing else).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/5ZJgF/

Comment: @SReject - In JavaScript variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope in which they appear. Your fiddle is not doing anything like what you think it is. The declarations will happen once, before anything else.

Comment: updated it. forgot about that little detail, I did :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no practical difference. Use whichever suits you best. You can tell JSLint to allow many `var` statements by adding the following directive at the top the file:

```
/*jslint vars: true */
```

Note that there is *[no difference in speed](http://jsperf.com/single-var-statement-vs-multiple-statements)* between the two variants:

[image]

The [part of the spec that deals with variable declarations](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) states the following:

> For each *VariableDeclaration* and *VariableDeclarationNoIn d* in *code*, in
>   source text order do
>
> - Let *dn* be the *Identifier* in *d*.
> - Let *varAlreadyDeclared* be the result of calling *env’s* HasBinding concrete
>     method passing *dn* as the argument.
> - If *varAlreadyDeclared* is false, then
>
>   - Call *env’s* CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn* and
>       *configurableBindings* as the arguments.
>   - Call *env’s* SetMutableBinding
>       concrete method passing *dn*, undefined, and *strict* as the arguments.

There is nothing in there that would differentiate between separate and combined `var` statements.