# JavaScript: can a variable have multiple values?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm fairly new to JavaScript beyond jQuery, and I was reading up on randomization in a JavaScript array & the shortcomings of using the Array.sort method with a random number. I see the recommendation instead is to use the Fisher-Yates shuffle. In looking at the JavaScript code for this method:

```
Array.prototype.randomize = function()
{
    var i = this.length, j, temp;
    while ( --i )
    {
        j = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i - 1) );
        temp = this[i];
        this[i] = this[j];
        this[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

I'm struck by this line:

```
var i = this.length, j, temp;
```

What's going on here? Is a variable being given multiple values, or is this shorthand for something?

Comment: This is going on: http://es5.github.io/#x12.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable can never have multiple values at the same time.

The code you give is shorthand for

```
var i = this.length;
var j;
var temp;
```

Syntax like that above is legal in most programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

`var i = this.length, j, temp;`

is the same as :

```
var i = this.length;
var j; // here the value is undefined
var temp; // same, temp has a an undefined value
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's the shorthand for:
`var i = this.length;
var j;
var temp;`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating three variables, and only the leftmost will be born with a value - in this case, whatever the value `this.length` is.

As pointed out by everyone else respondig to you question, it's the same as:

```
var i = this.length;
var j, temp;
```

Other languages like Java, C# and Visual Basic allow you to create variables with a similar syntax. I.E.:

I.e.:

```
// C# and Java
int i = this.length, j, temp;

// which is the same as:
int i = this.length;
int j, temp;
```

```
' Visual Basic
Dim i = this.length as Integer, j as Integer, temp as Integer

' Which is the same as:
Dim i = this.length as Integer
Dim j as Integer, temp as Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just multiple declaration of variables in a single line. It's equivalent to this:

```
var i, j, temp;
i = this.length;
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
var i;
var j;
var temp;
i = this.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

[The specification](http://es5.github.io/#x12.2) defines the variables statement to be the `var` keyword, followed by a **list** of variables declarations, separated by a comma:

```
VariableStatement :
    var VariableDeclarationList ;

VariableDeclarationList :
    VariableDeclaration
    VariableDeclarationList , VariableDeclaration
```

Note the recursive definition of `VariableDeclarationList`. It means that an unlimited number of variables declarations can follow a `var` keyword.

Hence

```
var foo, bar;
```

is the same as

```
var foo;
var bar;
```

Related question: [What is the advantage of initializing multiple javascript variables with the same var keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5455445/218196)