# JavaScript: Difference between defining variables `var x; var y;` vs `var x,y;`?

Tags: javascript

Case 1:

```
var x = null;
var y = 1;
var z = "hello";
```

Case 2:

```
var x = null, y = 1, z = "hello"
```

Are there any performance difference between the two? Or what's the difference?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: No performance enhancement, and if it were, it would be extremely minimal. Second case it just quicker and for developers easier to read (in theory). Syntax wise, literally no difference.

Comment: Related: [What is the advantage of initializing multiple javascript variables with the same var keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5455445/218196)

Comment: @Dandy - I find the second *harder* to read because it is all on one line.

Comment: @Dandy Syntax is *exactly* the difference. Performance and meaning-wise they're identical for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Whether the environment processes three variable declarations with one declarator each, or one variable declaration with three declarators doesn't really make a difference. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation

Comment: @deceze Good point, syntax was the wrong word to use. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote for this question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just writing style. No difference.

At a very fine level, maybe there will be some tokenising difference, but it should not (or rather would not) be a predictable performance variation as it depends on the interpreter/tokeniser implementation or design!!

From my experience, I think you have way more important things than declaration style to worry about for performance tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent and there *ought* to be no difference in performance although that could be down to the Javascript interpreter.

The first way (i.e. three separate statements) is certainly clearer.

Comment: *"The second way is certainly clearer"* – Mrmrmrrmmm… very debatable statement. :-3

Comment: @deceze I was going to say the same. First way seems clearer to me.

Comment: That typo could have started a great war of Javascript writing style.

Comment: First time I looked at this answer I disagreed (about clearer) but didn't want to argue, glad it was just a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

None at all it's just a preference; if you are running JsLint it will recommend chaining them together **where possible**.

http://davidshariff.com/blog/chaining-variable-assignments-in-javascript-words-of-caution/

This is a great blog about variable chaining.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no real difference between yours two way to do.

If you want a proper code, i think the first is the best, otherwise, the other make you win 2 lines. :)

Comment: If there's no real difference then why is the first one "proper code"?

Comment: Because in some schools or developer team there are rules for coding. That's why if he does not belong to them, it's not important and there is no difference